# datapiker no muestra calendario

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con el datetime de boostrap el cual es que no me muestra el calendario

ADJUNTO SCRIPT Y HTML

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Fenix | Escuela de Conductores</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     
  <link href="adminlte/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>


<div class='input-group date'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="fechaAsistencia">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
                </div>
```

```js
<script>
    $(function () 
    {
      $('#fechaAsistencia').datepiker();
    });
</script>
```

CON EL SIGUIENTE ERROR

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepiker is not a function

si alguien tiene alguna solucion o consejo por favor lo agradeceria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replique tu código y sólo falta agregar un atributo a tu div que es `data-provide="datepicker"`.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#fechaAsistencia').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class='input-group date' data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="col-md-6 form-control pull-right" id="fechaAsistencia">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Otra cosa, **estas incluyendo dos versiones de JQuery en tu código**, ojo con eso.

Nos comentas como te va

Comment: por cierta parte era eso y el error mas tonto que cometi fue que en el script me falto una letra le puse 'datepiker' y es 'datepicker' (me falto la c)